# sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

when i try to compile this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -f /mnt/c/Documents and Settings/user/Videos*.flv | while read -r file;
do
#-- get just the file name --#
name="${file%.*}"
echo ffmpeg -y -i $name.flv -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -strict experimental $name.mp4
done
```

It appears this error:

```
$./video.sh
./video2.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./video2.sh: line 7: `done'
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: (Unrelated to the issue, but https://shellcheck.net is your friend. It will point out numerous issues in your code.)

Comment: The code works for me (I mean it fails, but there aren’t any _syntax_ errors). Could it be something invisible in the file, e.g. carriage returns?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `ls -f /mnt/c/Documents and Settings/user/Videos*.flv` outputs? I would expect 3 error messages saying "no such file or directory". Try `for file in "/mnt/c/Documents and Settings/user/"Videos*.flv; do ...`